# How to do domain filtering in Linux?

Tags: linux, firewall, domain

Preferably something similar to `iptables`. Basically, I want to do domain filtering/whitelisting/blacklisting like I would with IPs in `iptables`. Are there any recommendations on how to do this?

Comment: what/why are you trying to block?  Are you trying to filter outgoing/incoming HTTP or SMTP or NTP?  Different tools can be used for different scenarios.

Comment: Couple of suggestions that might help you are http://denyhosts.sourceforge.net/faq.html and http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page.

Comment: @josten ideally you would use an HTTP proxy like [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/).  Blocking domain names in `iptables` can be [done](https://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1055023) but it may be dicey

Answer (score 11):

If you drop traffic using name resolution with iptables rules, the names will be resolved during the creation of that rule. If something change, you rule will not be valid anymore. This could be a solution(not a beautyfull one...):

```
# iptables -I FORWARD -p udp --dport 53 -m string --hex-string "|03|www|08|facebook|03|com" --algo bm -j DROP
```

From another host inside the LAN:

```
# host www.facebook.com
www.facebook.com A record not found, try again
```

Basically, your are saying to every dns packet(`udp/53`) that have the hexadecimal string of `www.facebook.com to` be dropped. Note that this will drop name resolution, and not the http traffic itself.

The hex numbers separated with pipes(`|03|www|08|facebook|03|com`) are the representation of the dot`.` simbol on dns queries. It will say how many of the following charaters will represent each part of a [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name)(host, domain, top-level domain) Example:

host: `mail.google.com`

hex representation: `04 6d 61 69 6c 06 67 6f 6f 67 6c 65 03 63 6f 6d`

"visual" representation: `04mail06google03com`

Getting the packet with tcpdump:

```
# tcpdump -i eth0 -X dst port 53

15:50:11.643672 IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx > ns4.google.com.domain: 16530 A? mail.google.com. (33)
        0x0000:  4500 003d 779a 4000 4011 b390 c949 4742  E..=w.@.@....IGB
        0x0010:  d8ef 260a 8424 0035 0029 0fc0 4092 0000  ..&..$.5.)..@...
        0x0020:  0001 0000 0000 0000 046d 6169 6c06 676f  .........mail.go
        0x0030:  6f67 6c65 0363 6f6d 0000 0100 01         ogle.com.....
```

But, remember:

- If your are trying to filter more specific traffig like smtp, ftp or http, a proxy of that protocol should be better.
- You are "hijacking" dns queries and not blocking the domain. Users are not that dumb ;)

Sources: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14096966/2231796) and [here](https://serverfault.com/q/404081/122772)

Comment: why algo type is bm ?

Comment: Algorithm Boyer-Moore - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm

Answer (score 5):

Maybe the answer to your question is too late, but recently I needed to solve a similar problem and google brings me here

After unsuccessful searches I wrote a small utility in C that intercepts DNS-responses, compares the domain name in it against given regex and lists matched IP addresses. Here it is: https://github.com/vmxdev/sidmat/

You don't need to set up your own DNS server, utility can catch DNS responses from any server

For example, to see facebook.com (and subdomains) ip addresses which are resolved right now you can run

```
# ./sidmat eth0 "^facebook\.com$|\.facebook\.com$"
173.252.120.6
...
```

where eth0 is network interface on router (or where DNS responses pass)

You can easily integrate it with iptables (or iptables with ipset)

But:

- utility is really simple. It does not performs many checks, so attacker can cheat it
- this technique is useless if users do not use DNS for name resolution

Comment: This is a cool little app. (with a few bugs, but still, very informative). One problem with DNS, though, is that it could have been cached. And as you mentioned, some DNS requests are now done through HTTPS.

Answer (score 4):

For blacklisting easiest way is probably to use **dnsmasq**

Install `dnsmasq`

```
$ sudo apt-get install dnsmasq
```

and add this line to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf`

```
address=/facebook.com/127.0.0.1
```

This will block [facebook.com](http://facebook.com) and all its subdomains.

Note: For ubuntu see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/150135/how-to-block-specific-domains-in-hosts-file/150180#150180).

Answer (score 2):

If running a local caching bind9 it is often realized by a `dummy-block`

```
zone "facebook.com" { type master; file "dummy-block"; };
```

and the `dummy-block` file:

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     localhost. root.localhost. (
                          2         ; Serial
                     604800         ; Refresh
                      86400         ; Retry
                    2419200         ; Expire
                     604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      localhost.
@       IN      A       127.0.0.1
*       IN      A       127.0.0.1
```

See also:

[Running BIND9 and ISC-DHCP](http://blog.bigdinosaur.org/running-bind9-and-isc-dhcp/) with `facebook.com` example.

[A Simple DNS-Based Approach for Blocking Web Advertising](http://collaboration.cmc.ec.gc.ca/science/rpn/biblio/ddj/Website/articles/SA/v13/i01/a3.htm)